# how to get session value in a handlebar template?

Tags: handlebars.js

Hi i am new to handlebar ,I am trying to get user_id from session with a custom helper i made in handlebar but i am getting an exception ,please help.

**registered helper**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getSessionValue', function (keyValue) {
debugger;
var out = '';
$.ajax({
    url: "/getSession",
    method: 'post',
    async: true,
    dataType: json,
    success :function(result){
        out = result['user_id'];
    }
});
return out;
});
```

**hanldebar template code snipet**

```
{{#getSessionValue}}
```

**error while compiling template**

```
    usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/helpers.js:15
    throw new Exception(mustache.sexpr.id.original + ' doesn\'t match ' + clos
          ^
Error: getSessionValue doesn't match if - 87:14
    at new Error (<anonymous>)
    at Error.Exception (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/exception.js:13:41)
    at Object.prepareBlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/helpers.js:15:11)
    at Object.anonymous (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js:35:21)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js:190:36)
    at HandlebarsEnvironment.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/base.js:18:17)
    at precompile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:389:17)
    at HandlebarsEnvironment.hb.precompile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars.js:22:12)
    at processTemplate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/lib/precompiler.js:109:80)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/handlebars/lib/precompiler.js:115:5
```

Comment: Looks like you have unclosed `{{#if}}` somewhere in your template.

Comment: sorry for late reply ! Yes the issue was unclosed handlebar tag !